# SharePoint Edit Mode Javascript error in edit mode

Tags: web-part, javascript, error, content-editor-web-part

I am not able to edit the page from the browser. I used to change and edit webparts when suddenly in the edit mode everything looks like it is locked/stalled. When I open the debugger tool, I saw a JavaScript error that is not shown in other pages in edit mode:

> sp.ui.rte.js?rev=rOOAA8PEAq0mDdsIJm30zA%3D%3D:2

[image: Javascript error in edit mode]

The page toolbar looks like this and it is not clickable:

[image: Edit Toolbar]

When i Try to edit a webpart nothing happens:

[image]

I am not sure how this error is happening and why, can someone help?

Comment: does it work in IE ?, is this page using the same page layout of the other ones where it works?  It looks like there is some javascript conflict maybe on this page layout you are using custom javascript?

Comment: @L.V.SharepointArchitect the only javascript i added is native js just to change a text all the other pages are working fine, and the page is not editable even on IE, Firefox and Chrome, i am using oslo as masterpage i changed the design using the css through the sharepoint designer.

Comment: Have you installed any Cumulative Update packs?

Comment: no  nothing, and the weird is that in this particular page, no where else, i tried to restore previous versions of this page, but nothing happened. And it is frustrating since i can't change the content neither delete it, the error appear to a null of a, and not a code error, which means that there is value missing.

Comment: did you fix this problem. I am having same issue at the moment and would like to know how you tackled this issue.